# GDAL/OGR in C++: Merge multiple vector datasets to single

Tags: gdal, vector, ogr, c++, append

I need to merge multiple kml files into a single one.

I found that I could use "ogr2ogr -append" but I have to do it through c++ and my Google-fu hasn't been successful so far.
So, any ideas?

Also, how to add new fields(and manually values in that field) in a kml file (through C++ again). Probably something to do with OGR_Fld_Create?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "merge," are you intending to union the geometries and store them as one layer, or store each as a new layer? If it's the former, you can export the geometries from a layer into GEOS using something like this (just to get started -- I cribbed this from some code I wrote for a program):

```
const GEOSContextHandle_t gctx = OGRGeometry::createGEOSContext();
GDALDataset *srcDs, *dstDs;
OGRLayer *layer;
OGRFeature *feat;
geos::geom::Geometry *geom;

srcDs = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpenEx(shapefile, GDAL_OF_VECTOR|GDAL_OF_READONLY, NULL, NULL, NULL);
layer = srcDs->GetLayer(0);

while((feat = layer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL) {
    geom = (geos::geom::Geometry *) feat->GetGeometryRef()->exportToGEOS(gctx);
   // .. do something with geom
}
```

You'd use GEOS to union the geom instances together, then write out to a new shapefile.

If you want to add fields to a layer, something like:

```
OGRFieldDefn fstddev("stddev", OFTReal);
layer->CreateField(&fstddev);
feat->SetField("stddev", 1234.0);
```

You create the field on the layer using the field definition, then set the value of the field on the feature itself (since every feature can have a unique value for that field.)

Figuring out how to work with OGR/GDAL can be challenging. I use the [tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html) and the [API docs](http://www.gdal.org/annotated.html) to figure it out. Note that OGR has changed significantly with GDAL2.0 (which I'm using here.) As you can see, vector data is now manipulated using GDALDataset.

Comment: Your creation field tips worked as charm! Thanks


Clarification: I want to merge multiple 1-layered kmls to a single 1-layered


so that the final will contain all features from all input kmls in a single layer.


Is there no other way through gdal/ogr? I would like to avoid another new library.


Unfortunately, as I wrote [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173510/gdal-ogr-in-c-opening-a-vector-file) I have some opening file problems so I cannot enter field values or check the union through GEOS you suggested.

Comment: There is actually a [Union](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#a939bb2b738337a3af1fc715187822171) method the the API, but it requires GEOS anyway. GDAL has no built-in computational geometry abilities.

Comment: I don't need to unite geometries. I want to sum features from different 1-layered files to a single 1-layered file.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do it manually with multiple [OGRFeature::SetFrom](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html#a05c7db31f9585ca8ec6d087225bffcf8) from one file to the other.
[if I manage to open the kmls](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173510/gdal-ogr-in-c-opening-a-vector-file) that is.

Comment: Oh, right. Brain fart. In that case, just create new features and add them to the layer. No need to worry about GEOS as far as I know (though I haven't tested this.) Sorry about the confusion.